# How to close an expired condor position in thinkorswim

Tags: options, thinkorswim

I have ten condor positions in a stock that expired last Friday. The condor was profitable and am now trying to figure out how to close the position. I thought that this was something tos would do automatically, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are closing 3 possibilities with an option:

- You BTC or STC it
- It expires worthless
- It's ITM and is assigned/exercised

The last possibility warrants some additional explanation.  If an option is one cent or more  ITM at expiration, the Option Clearing Corp (OCC)  will automatically exercise/assign your options whether they are  long or short.  This is called Exercise by Exception.  For equity options, you will end up with a position in the underlying (index options are cash settled).

If you are long an option, you can designate to the OCC via your broker that your options are not auto exercised at expiration.  This would make sense if they are ITM by pennies and your commission to close the position exceeds the ITM amount.

You didn't specify whether:

- You were long or short the condor
- Whether the underlying was outside the wings or between the body and the wings at expiration
- If this the underlying is an index  or an equity

Without that info, there's no way to know what the outcome will be.  The best case scenario is that you get a cash credit in the amount of your profit.  The worst case scenario is that you end up with a long or a short position in the underlying, possibly unexpected.

The short answer is that you can't close an expired option.  Given that today is Wednesday and the options expired last Friday, you should know the disposition of your position by now.

Comment: Well what I said wasn't completely accurate. I was using the OnDemand feature of tos to test long condors. The price of the option at expiration was withing the profit area. I fast forward to the end of the exipiration date, then to the following Monday. I'm pretty sure that real options trades will automatically be exercised, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Suppose the stock is $100 and you have a 90p/95p/105c/110c iron condor that cost $2.  Expiration profit zone is below $93 and above $107.  If above $110 or below $90, you make $3 ($5 less the cost).  If the underlying finishes b/t $90 and $95 or b/t $105 and  $110, your long legs will be exercised and you'll end up long or short 100 shares per iron condor on Monday morning.  Now you have directional market risk far and above the previous $90 and $110 limits of the newly expired IC.  Close or roll the ITM legs by expiration.